# How can I do this custom Select All function to work?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have two connected classes: the `Smartphone` and the `Model`. The `Smartphone` contains a collection of `Model` that looks like this:

```
public class Smartphone
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
}
```

while the `Model`:

```
public class Smartphone
{
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I added another property in the `Model` class:

```
public const string IsSelectPropertyName = "IsSelect";

private bool _isSelect = false;

public bool IsSelect
{
    get
    {
        return _isSelect ;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(IsSelectPropertyName, ref _isSelect , value);
    }
}
```

Then the `SelectAll` in the `Smartphone` class:

```
private bool _selectAll;

public bool SelectAll
{
    get
    {
        return _selectAll;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectAll = value;
        foreach (var item in Models)
        {
            item.IsSelect = value;
        }
        Set(() => SelectAll, ref _selectAll, value);
    }
}
```

The problem here is if one item is unchecked, the `SelectAll` is still checked. What I tried so far is having this function in `Smartphone` class :

```
public void CheckSelected()
{
    bool isUnchecked = Models.Select(item => item.IsSelect).AsQueryable().All(value => value == false);

    if (isUnchecked)
    {
        SelectAll = false;
    } else
    {
        SelectAll = true;
    }
}
```

However, if added into the `IsSelect` property in the `Model` class like this:

```
public const string IsSelectPropertyName = "IsSelect";

private bool _isSelect = false;

public bool IsSelect
{
    get
    {
        return _isSelect ;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(IsSelectPropertyName, ref _isSelect , value);
        if (Smartphone != null)
        {
            Smartphone.CheckSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

I got error like:

> StackoverflowException

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get in your `SelectAll` and `IsSelect` setters all the time, as you call `CheckSelect()` -> `SelectAll` -> `IsSelect` -> `CheckSelect()` in a loop.

One possible solution is to react in the setter of a property only when the value has actually be changed. The code might look like this:

```
get
{
    return _isSelect ;
}
set
{
    if (_isSelect == value)
        return; // don't do anything, nothing has been changed
    Set(IsSelectPropertyName, ref _isSelect , value);
    if (Smartphone != null)
    {
        Smartphone.CheckSelected();
    }
}
```

You will get inside the setter for the first time, but at the second time the field `_isSelect` has already been changed and you exit the setter with the `return` statement in the `if()` body. This also means that the following `Smartphone.CheckSelected();` call is not executed, "breaking" the loop.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Though this removed the issue with the error, this also make my `SelectAll` not working anymore.